# Hilbert transform/contour integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{1-\lambda \cos x}\frac{1}{t-x} dx$

Tags: integration, contour-integration

Is it possible to find closed form solutions for the following integral (which is a Hilbert transform)
$$P.V.\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n x}{1-\lambda \cos x}\frac{1}{t-x} dx,$$
for $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|\lambda|<1$, $ t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n$ a natural number. Here, P.V. means principal value.

Comment: ${\tt Mathematica}$ said it doesn't $converge$. Yes, I used the ${\tt Principal\ Value \to True}$ option.

Comment: @FelixMarin The p.v. integral exists. The integrals over $(-\infty, t - 1]$ and $[t + 1, \infty)$ converge by Dirichlet's test because the integral of $\sin(n x)/(1 - \lambda \cos x)$ over a period is zero, and the p.v. integral over $[t - 1, t + 1]$ exists because the integrand is $f(n, t)/(t - x)$ plus a function with a removable singularity. The transform is
$$\frac
 {\left( \frac {1 - \sqrt {1 - \lambda^2}} \lambda \right)^{\! n} - \cos n t}
 {1 - \lambda \cos t}.$$

Comment: @Maxim I’ll go back to the integral. Thanks.